# What is the best way to deal with short strings in a list while extracting values using .split() method in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I am new in programming, and I am trying to take out from a list of strings (list1) the strings [0] [1] [5] and [6] after applying a .split (to extract values separated by spaces) in each string.

List1:

```
0 (row)
str (datatype)
81 (size)
                  COMPANY NAME                                     

1
str
81
                                                                                

2
str
81
                                                                                

3
str
81
                                                                                

4
str
81
                                                                                

5
str
28
C:\UQ5\USER\ARL\Job\JOB.157

6
str
81
Sample ident  =** SAMPLE_1**    0.00-3.00                                         

7
str
41
                                        

8
str
23
     Method   :  X_UQ.

9
str
1


10
str
81
          Compound m/m%   StdErr  | El     m/m%     StdErr                      

11
str
81
          ------ -------- ------- | --     -------- -------                     

12
str
81
         ** CaO   **    **55.00**    0.25   | **Ca **       **39.32**    0.18                       

13
str
81
         ** SiO2  **    ** 1.06 **   0.05   | **Si  **      ** 0.496 **  0.024                      

14
str
81
         ** MgO **       **0.267**   0.013  |** Mg  **       **0.161**   0.008    `
```

Thus I am using the following Code trying to extract the **bold ** values in a dataframe:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=("Sample", "Compound", "Value"))

path_to_file =  (r"...\CL 23-07 M1.txt")
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines: 
        line_split = line.split()
        name_gral= lines[6].split()
        name_gral = name_gral[3] 
        cmp = line[0] #first 0 and 1, then I'll extract 5 and 6
        val = line[1] 
        temp_list = ({"Sample": name_gral, "Compound": cmp, "Value": val})
        df_final = df_final.append(temp_list, ignore_index=True)
```

But obviously I can not pass from the row 9 because it has less than 1 in size after the .split(), how do I tell python to place a "-1" in those cases? Or what would you recommend me? Because the .txt files a filled with rows with just 1 space-bar.

The goal is to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
index  Sample  Compound  Value
1 SAMPLE_1  CaO     55.00
2 SAMPLE_1 Ca      39.32
3 SAMPLE_1 SiO2     1.06
...
```

I was trying to obtain a  dataframe with the mentioned values, but the code tells me "IndexError: list index out of range" because there are some strings in the list of strings that are really short. So the code can not continue functioning after a few lines.

Comment: `len(line)` tells you the number of items in a list if `line` is a list. You can then use this in an `if` to react on the number of present items.

Comment: michael-butscher I'll check that out, maybe that way I can use an if statement

Comment: it isn't clear if `List1` is the actual data you are working on or some intermediate product?  Is `List1` the *exact* contents of the data file `CL 23-07 M1.txt`?  If not, can you update your post by pasting in enough (exact) lines from that datafile as a code block?

Comment: @AirSquid it is the exact contents

Comment: Interesting.... so it has the lines with "11 str 81" and such in the data file?

Comment: @AirSquid I know, it was presented in such disorganized way on purpose

Comment: Presented?  Is this a H/W assignment or a real-world issue?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea from @Michael Butscher, i created this code line that worked:

```
path_to_file =  (r"...\CLSA 23-07 M1-M8\CL 23-07 M1.txt")
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line_split = line.split()
        obtain= lines[6].split()
        name_gral = obtain[3]
        if len(line) > 75:
            obtain_2= line.split()
            print (obtain_2[0:1])
            print (obtain_2[1:2])
            print ("###")
            cmp = obtain_2[0:1]
            val = obtain_2[1:2] 
            temp_list = ({"Sample": name_gral, "Compound": cmp, "Value": val})
            df_final = df_final.append(temp_list, ignore_index=True)
        elif len(line) <= 75:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

It created the following dataframe:

```
Sample  Compound    Value

> 19    CL23-07 ['TiO2']    ['0.0050'] 20   CL23-07 ['Nd2O3']   ['0.0048']
> 21    CL23-07 ['V2O5']    ['0.0035'] 22   CL23-07 ['MnO'] ['0.0030']
> 23    CL23-07 ['NiO'] ['0.0022'] 24   CL23-07 ['IrO2']    ['0.0018']
> 25    CL23-07 ['KnownConc=']  ['0'] 26    CL23-07 ['F']   ['0.06']
> 27    CL23-07 ['CeO2']    ['0.0040'] 28   CL23-07 ['BaO'] ['0.0035']
> 29    CL23-07 ['La2O3']   ['0.0027']
```

I know it has weird characters , but it can be now easily filtered out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expressions (`re` module):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

ident = re.search(r'Sample ident\s*=\s*(\S+)', data).group(1)
data = data.split('------', maxsplit=1)[-1]

all_data = []
for i, d in enumerate(re.findall(r'([A-Z]\S+)\s*([\d+.-]+)', data), 1):
    all_data.append((i, ident, *d))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['index', 'Sample', 'Compound', 'Value'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index    Sample Compound  Value
0      1  SAMPLE_1      CaO  55.00
1      2  SAMPLE_1       Ca  39.32
2      3  SAMPLE_1     SiO2   1.06
3      4  SAMPLE_1       Si  0.496
4      5  SAMPLE_1      MgO  0.267
5      6  SAMPLE_1       Mg  0.161
```